# OpenGL - Rotating moon around sun without it spinning?

Tags: c, opengl, math, 3d, geometry

I'm working on a graphics model of the Moon rotating around the Earth. Right now, the Moon spins on its y axis while rotating around the Earth. How can I prevent the Moon from spinning but still allow it to orbit? Here's the code..

Edit: 
Added an animation video to demonstrate problem:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ltGV4pXD5Cs

```
void DrawInhabitants(GLint nShadow)
{
    static GLfloat yRot = 0.0f;         // Rotation angle for animation 

    if(nShadow == 0)
    {
        yRot += 0.2f; 
    } 

    // Draw the randomly located spheres
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureObjects[MOON_TEXTURE]); 

    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.1f, -2.5f);

        glPushMatrix();
            glRotatef(-yRot * 2.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            glTranslatef(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            gltDrawSphere(0.1f,21, 11);
        glPopMatrix();

        if(nShadow == 0)
        {
            // Torus alone will be specular
            glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, fBrightLight);
        }

        glRotatef(-yRot, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureObjects[EARTH_TEXTURE]);
        gltDrawSphere(0.3f, 21, 11);
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, fNoLight);
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Comment: Try *un*-rotating just after translating.

Comment: Hello, I added a video link to my post to show what is happening.

Comment: @luserdroog, Thanks :) Un-rotating did the trick.

Comment: You're welcome. I had a very similar issue with placing polygons around a polygon. Another way would be to calculate the position without using a coordinate-system-rotation at all. But affine-composability makes it simple to undo the effect.

Comment: It is not entirely clear what exactly goes on in that video. The Moon should always face the Earth the same way, so it *does* need to rotate around its y axis with the same angular velocity it rotates around Earth.

Comment: @luserdroog: Actually since the moon is tidally locked you can save the "unrotating" simply by translating before rotation (in r-multiplied matrix terms the rotatation-revolution comes first then).

Comment: @Phil: Why change it? The moon is tidally locked and that's very close to the motion the real moon has.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're rotating the coordinate system in order to place the moon in its desired relative position. This rotation is global so it affects the orientation of the moon as well. You need to undo the rotation after translating, so you have "translation sandwich"

```
rotate a
translate
rotate -a
```